# text search to distinguish rails projects from other types of ruby web applications - merb/sinatra/ramaze

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sinatra, merb, ramaze

If I want to perform a search on a directory that contains thousands of different ruby web applications and I want to find only those directories that contain rails projects, what text would I need to look for within each directory to uniquely distinguish the rails projects from the other project types?

At the moment, I have decided to search based on:

```
config.gem
```

which I believe is a syntax that is used only by Rails, not by Merb, Sinatra or Ramaze. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While `config.gem` will probably work you might want to search for the file `script/server` which every Rails app will have. Who knows, maybe some strange person has decided to change the block parameter `config` to be named something else? It is probably far less likely they've changed or moved `script/server` though.